# JAVA: Invalid literal hex number

Tags: java

Why am i getting a "Invalid hex literal number" for this

```
int number = 0xgetInt();
```

and not for this

```
int number = 0x555;
```

Comment: what's `0xgetInt()`? `0x555` corresponds to 1365 in decimal notation (`0x` is a prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x` is the start of literal and is converted into the appropriate value at **compile time** where as `getInt()` is evaluated at runtime.

You probably want

```
int number = Integer.parseInt( getNext(), 16)
```

Comment: Wow was really frustrated with this thanks.

Comment: I doubt that is what he wants. He already has an `int`, he seems to want hex to me.

Comment: @EJP I assumed the OP has the number in hexidecimal format and wants to store it as an int.

Answer (score 2):

`getInt()` is a function call, not a "literal number" as the exception says. There's no reason to try to convert that `int` to hex at this particular spot, since it's stored as a variable anyway.

Comment: Because it's stored as an `integer` variable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A ["hex" or hexadecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) can only contain the digits 0-9 and characters a-f (or A-F). In java, prefixing a number with "0x" [indicates to the compiler that it's a hexadecimal integer literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). `0xgetInt()` is therefore interpreted as an integral value, but it contains invalid hexadecimal digits. `0x555`, on the other hand, is a [valid hex value that corresponds to 1365 decimal](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter). If `0xgetInt()` is supposed to be a method name, you'll have to change it to get rid of the "0x" prefix to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't start a Java identifier with a number, and because a number can start with `0x` but it can't continue with `getInt`. It's not valid Java, at the lexical level.

It's unclear what you're trying to do here. If you're trying to convert the result of getInt() to hex, you're barking up the wrong tree, it's binary, you would need to convert it to a `String` with `Integer.toString(getInt(), 16).`